# Truth Tables for Temporal Operators?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I would like to know whether we can construct truth tables for the following temporal operators in temporal logic as we do in propositional logic .

```
                 G
                 X
                 F
                 U
```

Comment: What are these temporal operators?

Comment: These are the operators that we work with in Linear Temporal Logic. Like the operators  /\ , \/ , -> , ¬ we  have in propositional logic

Comment: Hmm, what is the underlying modal logic? I know that we can construct analogues of truth tables for *S5*, but I'm unaware of any similar construction for other systems.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so : operators for *tense logic* are modal operators, and not truth-functional operators.

See in *SEP* the entry on [Temporal Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/)